# SharePoint Calculated Field Remove text from string

Tags: sharepoint

My 'Title' field returns the following results:

ie: Gold.png

I want to remove '.png' and just leave the word 'Gold'

Here's my calculated field but it's throwing out an error message.

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(".png",Title,1)),[Title],REPLACE([Title],SEARCH("&",[Title],1),1,""))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Something like this: =REPLACE([Title],".png","") but this doesn't work too.

Comment: I tried with this: =REPLACE([Title],SEARCH(".png",[Title]),"1","") but it's only removing '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=REPLACE([Title],SEARCH(".png",[Title]),"4","")